# How to provide pipeline parameters in creating build definition using Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I can able to create the build definition using Azure DevOps REST API. When I ran the build definition from the portal, it is not using `azure-pipeline.yml` file which is part of the codebase in Azure Repos. The pipeline file(`azure-pipeline.yml`) includes the docker task which will build an image for the application. But this operation is not working. To figure out this problem, I have created two definitions.

1. Created the build definition manually from Azure DevOps Portal.
2. Created the build definition using Azure DevOps REST API.

The first approach works as expected. It is creating a docker image for the application and the docker tasks works. The second approach didn't work and it just check out the source code from the repository.

I came across the process parameters which include the path of the pipeline file. I don't know how to configure the same using REST API.

I'm following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

> **EDIT 1**

```
{
"name": "myapp2",
"badgeEnabled": "true",
"queue": {
    "name": "Hosted Ubuntu 1604",
    "pool": {
        "name": "Hosted Ubuntu 1604",
        "isHosted": true
    }
},
"jobAuthorizationScope": "projectCollection",
"jobTimeoutInMinutes": 60,
"jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
"quality": "definition",
"type" : "build",
"process": {
    "type": 2
},
"processParameters" : {
    "inputs" : [{
        "name" : "azure-pipeline.yml",
        "required" : true
    }]
}
```

Rest of the configuration is related to `repositories`.

> Creating Build Definition in Portal

[image]

> Creating Build Definition using Azure DevOps REST API

[image]

Comment: Can you share the both pipelines?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Please find the edited portion in the question. I used this file to create the build definition using REST API calls. I didn't get the file for the manual approach.

Comment: Can you share the build definition UI?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I have included the pictures of both approach in the question.

Answer (score 1):

From above post if you already have the yaml pipeline azure-pipeline.yml. There is no need to call Create Definition api to create a same one with the azure-pipeline.yml as parameter. you can call then queue the pipeline yaml manually or via [Build Queue API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

If you want to use api to create definition, You can first use [Get Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) api to call an existing build pipeline definition, so that you can refer to the returned response to check what are the properties need to be configured for the **Create Definition** api.

Here is example to [Create VSTS Build Definitions using PowerShell](http://chen.about-powershell.com/2018/07/create-vsts-build-definitions-using-powershell/), Additionally to this blog, you can define the pipeline tasks(defined in `process:{phases:[{steps:}]}`)  by referring to the response from Get Definition api.

As you can see to define a build pipeline using api is complicated, and it is not suggested as discussed in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/62947/creating-a-build-definition-via-api). The most convenient way to create a pipeline is via GUI manually or using yaml.

> Update:

If you call the Get Definition api to get the json format definition of an existing yaml pipeline. You will see there is no `processParameters` property.
So you donot need to define `processParameters` property when you use api to create a yaml pipeline. Yon only to  define the yaml file in process property `"process": { "yamlFilename": "azure-pipelines.yml", "type": 2}`.

For testing purpose, I firstly get the json format definition of an existing yaml pipeline and then modified a little bit of the json file. Then I delete the yaml pipeline from azure pipeline UI. Lastly I use **Create Definiton API** to create the yaml pipeline. Then yaml pipeline get created as expected.

The last screenshot you posted in your question is in the classic pipeline. Yaml pipeline doesnot have the `Parameters` section.

property `processParameters` will define this `Parameters` section. It is used to link all important arguments for tasks used across the build definition. check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/parameters?view=azure-devops) for more information about processParameters in Classic pipeline.

[image]

Comment: After creating the build definition using REST API, I used build queue REST API to run the definition. But It is not using the pipeline file from the codebase. From the logs, I didn't get the docker tasks being invoked. I believed it doesn't use the pipeline file.

Comment: From the above post, the `processParameters` is not working. It didn't include the path of pipeline file in build process parameter in the definition settings.

Comment: How to provide the pipeline path in JSON request body?

Comment: I called an existing yaml pipeline, the yaml file seems defined in process property `"process":  { "yamlFilename":  "azure-pipelines.yml",     "type":  2}`

Comment: Yeah. I tried with that approach as well. It didn't include `yamlFilename` as build paramater in the definition settings.

Comment: Do we need provide `azure-pipelines.yml` in both `process` and `processParameters`?

Comment: Hi  @Kumaresh Babu N S Sorry for the late reply. There is no need to define `processParameters` for yaml pipeline. You only need to provide azure-pipelines.yml in `process`. I updated above answer.

Comment: Hey @Levi Lu-MSFT No worries. I have fixed the issue. Yes, You're right. I removed the `processParameters` from the request body. I have resolved all the issues and it is mapping to the pipeline yaml file. Thanks Levi.